# Handling Price & Currency in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, currency, rails-models

I'm following this tutorial http://pauldeardorff.com/2013/08/14/handling-currencies-in-ruby-on-rails-apps/  about adding a price and currency selection in a rails app.

In a starter app I have my modules set up exactly like the simple tutorial

My problem seems to arrive when I first render a new action for my product class. The tutorial advises to create a money_attributes file within the rails Lib folder.

```
# lib/money_attributes.rb
module MoneyAttributes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def money_attributes *args      
      args.each do |attribute|
        cents_attribute = "#{attribute}_in_cents"
        define_method attribute do
          send(cents_attribute).try("/", 100.0)
        end

        define_method "#{attribute}=" do |value| 
          value.gsub!(/[^\d.]/,"") if value.is_a? String           
          send("#{cents_attribute}=", value.try(:to_f).try("*", 100))
        end

        define_method "#{attribute}_money" do                                
          Money.new(send("#{attribute}_in_cents").to_f || 0,send("currency")).format 
        end 

        attr_accessible attribute if accessible_attributes.include?(cents_attribute)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My app spits out undefined local variable or method `accessible_attributes'.

I have an Idea of what's wrong because the 'accessible_attributes' was discontinued in rails 4 I believe. My issue is I have no idea how I would fix this method. Also my control strong parameters looks as following

```
     products_controller.rb
```

......
        private

```
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:price, :currency)
    end
```

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this I'll greatly appreciate it or might have a better method in mind that matches the tutorial. My issue is that I would like the price and currency selection separate within my models form. just like specified within this tutorial. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute protection is now done in the controller (via strong params, as you have implemented), so the `attr_accessible attribute if accessible_attributes.include?(cents_attribute)` line can be removed.